# Angular bootstrap calendar refreshview

Tags: angularjs, calendar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have broadcast new event date from first controller.

Second controller check broadcast and update the calendar.

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('firstCtrl',function(){
 $scope.$watch(function () { return $scope.calData;},function(newVal,oldVal){ 
   if(oldVal!==newVal){
     $timeout(function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('updateCalData',$scope.zoneData);
    });
   }
  }); 
})
.controller('secCtrl',function(){
  $rootScope.$on('updateCalData',function(event,args){
  eventCalendar(args);  
 })
  function eventCalendar(){
    //........
  }
})
```

PROBLEM

Currently views doesn't get populated with new event data. I have to manual refresh the page to see the changes.

I am using Ionic Framework

Thanks, any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use scope.apply

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
          $scope.$apply()
        }
```

Comment: print console on function eventCalendar() to check weather it called@shrijan

Comment: Yes $scope.events gets updated with new set of array. As i said then you reload page calendar gets updated but it doesnt get updated by itself.

Comment: what is  $scope.events?@shrijan

Comment: Events is object passed to angular bootstrap calendar

Comment: <mwl-calendar events="events" view="calendarView" view-     title="viewTitle" view-date="viewDate" on-timespan-click="timespanClicked(calendarDate)" on-event-click="eventClicked(calendarEvent);" on-view-change-click="false" slide-box-disabled = "false"></mwl-calendar>

Comment: May be its a scope issue.Declare $scope.events as a key value of a dictionary.$scope.calevent={};$scope.calevent.events=newvalue@shrijan

Comment: I finally able to fix this.

Use vm.events  instead of scope.events fix for me.